# vanilla JavaScript set style on body

Tags: javascript

Why does this not work?

Using vanilla JavaScript to set the style on body tag?

```
<html>
   <body style="display:none;">
       test
   </body>
   <script>
       document.getElementsByTagName("body").style.display = "block";
   </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Because [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementsByTagName) returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/NodeList), not a single element. Treat it as array:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.display = "block";
```

Or even simpler in case of `body`:

```
document.body.style.display = "block";
```

Comment: Is that posible because there will only every be one body tag? Is document.input.style.display = "block";  allowed?

Comment: @Hello-World No, it is not possible for `input` or other elements, only for `body`. In case of other elements, just iterate the `NodeList` returned from `getElementsByTagName()` and set style to each iterated element.

Comment: @Hello-World: Yes and no. `document.body` is a special property referring to the body element, because, as you said, there can only be one. It does not work for any other elements.

Answer (score 7):

If you want the `body` tag you can simply use `document.body`. See the demo.

```js
console.time("show body");
document.body.style.display = "none";

setTimeout(function () {
    console.timeEnd("show body");
    document.body.style.display = "block";
}, 3000);
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
```

Answer (score 4):

I used the following solution:

```
<script>
    function changeDisplay(){
        document.body.style.display = 'block';
    }

    setTimeout(function () { changeDisplay(); }, 0);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

while `body` is part of the document itself you don't have to call getElementBy..., you just say it directly `document.body.style.display = "block";`