# How do I programmatically set the width of a HTMLElement?

Tags: javascript, dom

```
refs: {
    someElement: HTMLDivElement;
};

this.$refs.someElement.clientWidth = 100;
```

I am getting:

> Cannot assign to 'clientWidth' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

or

> Cannot assign to 'offsetWidth' because it is a constant or a read-only property.

Comment: `.style.width`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vanilla JavaScript set style on body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519527/vanilla-javascript-set-style-on-body)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
this.$refs.someElement.style.width = '100px';
```